# Google Fit - Aggregate Wheel RPM data

Tags: android, google-fit

I am currently trying to implement a Google Fit Android application. I want to read aggregated values which were created by the application. This is working well for all but one datasource, namely the **`com.google.cycling.wheel_revolution.rpm`**.

In the developer documentation to aggregated datatypes (https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types#data_types_for_aggregate_data) there is no dedicated aggregated datatype for wheel rotation.

If I try to aggregate the wheel rotation datatype I get following error:

`Unsupported input data type specified for aggregation: DataType{com.google.cycling.wheel_revolution.rpm[rpm(f)]}`

Is it possible to aggregate the wheel rotation? If not, how can I define a custom datatype with a custom aggregation datatype containing min, max, average similar to `com.google.heart_rate.bpm` and `com.google.heart_rate.summary`

Best Regards
Markus

PS: If i try to aggregate using the REST API I receive a response with empty datapoints.
This is my request body:

`{
    "startTimeMillis": 1479678504211,
    "endTimeMillis": 1479682677569,
    "aggregateBy": [
    {
        "dataTypeName": ":com.google.cycling.wheel_revolution.rpm.summary",
        "dataSourceId": "raw:com.google.cycling.wheel_revolution.rpm:[my_application_id]:"
    }
  ],
  "bucketByTime": {
     "durationMillis": 60000
  }
}`

Comment: From your error "Unsupported input data type specified for aggregation wheel_revolution", it means that your data is not supported for this aggregation. So make sure that your input data is valid and it is stated in this [docu](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#TYPE_CYCLING_WHEEL_RPM) that for this aggregation, you should left unset the start time. The different data sources will monitor the RPMs for different amounts of time before calculating the RPM. This should be indicated as part of the data source and not the data point.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks aggregation for wheel rotation is not possible. According to the documentation ([Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#getAggregatesForInput(com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType)) the function `List<DataType> getAggregatesForInput (DataType inputDataType)` returns the aggregation data type for a given input. The result is empty for `com.google.cycling.wheel_revolution.rpm`.

Therefore, aggregation is not possible for wheel_revolution.rpm. And most probably it also wont work for custom datatypes (not tested yet).